# Android Studio,How to deploy apk to system path?

Tags: android, android-studio

My application should be install to system/app. But when install the apk by android studio,it always install at /data/local/.Like this

```
Installing com.*
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.*"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.*
Success
```

Then how can I install to `system/app` by android Studio, is it pissible?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with system applications, system applications are factory applications and we can not install under system/app folder unless device is rooted.

If your device is rooted then just copy your apk inside system/app folder and restart the device the apk will be installed.

OR write an application which will download in data section then when user run that application download and copy the app inside system/app but this is also in rooted devices.

Comment: I can do it by command now.But can I install system app by android studio?

Comment: Can I change the run command in android studio?I don't know where to edit it.

Comment: In rooted device you can use run but I am unaware to change the run command in Android Studio

Comment: I tried to use cp from sdcard to system/priv-app but it doesnt work whY?